# location/scale invariant priors

Tags: bayesian, prior, uninformative-prior

I'm trying to understand what's the motivation behind these priors, and why they are used.

I understand that for location parameters of some distribution, you want it to be invariant of movement. e.g. if $x \sim N(\mu,1)$ then $y = x + c \sim N(\mu + c, 1)$.

How does this has anything to do with the priors? I mean we are changing the problem completely if we are looking at $x$ or if we are looking at $y$. Why should we expect that the prior won't change?

Also, it is said that the prior here will be **uniform**. From where to where? Is it uniform across the entire $ \rm I\!R$? But isn't it then not defined? And if you are going to set some boundaries, what's the justification for that?

Same questions apply to scale invariant.

Comment: This is a prior choice, hence there is no absolute reason in using it. The rationale for using invariant priors is that the change of location, of scale, of both, or of anything that corresponds to the action of a group, should not impact our prior modelling if we have no specific prior information about the parameter. Whether the temperature data is measure in Kelvin, in Centigrade, or in Fahrenheit is unimportant if one does not know the specification of the measure temperature(s).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so my attempt to partially answer my own question, given what Xi'an said, and my further understanding:

1. It doesn't matter that the prior distribution is improper - i.e. that it's not a valid distribution. Bayesian's are willing to live with that as long as the posterior is proper. And still it does have some intuition understanding, i.e. $\propto 1$ translates intuitively to "all values are equally likely", or "I have no information has to what value it may take". As one of my professor put it: **lack of information is also information**.
2. If it's a "location" parameter, then the pdf is of the form $f_\theta(y)=f(y-\theta)$, i.e. the pdf only depends on the difference between $y$ and the parameter. If I change the parameter, I will get the exact same shape of the distribution, only shifted. So no information on this location parameters, means that I want the prior to be translation invariant, $\pi(\theta) = \pi(\theta-\theta_0) = Const. \Rightarrow \pi(\theta)\propto1$. Otherwise it would mean I do know something about the parameter, that in certain location it is more/less probable than other.
3. If it's a "scale" parameter, then the pdf is of the form $f_\theta(y)=f(y/\theta)/\theta$, i.e. if we change the scale of $y$ say to $z=\alpha y$, then the new pdf will be $f_\theta(z)=f(z/\alpha\theta)/\alpha\theta$. The pdf only depends on the parameter on the scale $y/\theta$ times a normalizing constant. If we define $u=\ln y \Rightarrow y=e^u$. The pdf of the new variable is then $f_U(u)=e^uf_Y(e^u/\theta)/\theta=e^{u-\ln \theta}f_Y(e^{u-\ln \theta})$. I.e. the pdf of the new variable, turned our scale parameter to a location parameter. Because now the new function only depends on the (ln of the) parameter by it's difference to the variable. So like before $\ln \theta \propto 1$. So for the prior $\theta$ itself: $f(\theta)=f_{\ln \Theta}(\ln \theta)\frac{1}{\theta}\propto 1\cdot\frac{1}{\theta}$